# Identify this BMX logo please?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

Hi all, having trouble identifying this logo found on my Bmx frame- any ideas?

Many thanks

---

More info:  It was bought with all high end parts- and was said to be WTP Justice or other WTP frame—couldn’t find other markings but will check in crank space and other areas for any more.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: You could try browsing here:
https://bmxmuseum.com/
They also seem to have an active forum, so may be able to help out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a "We The People" bicycle logo
You can find the logo in several of [their bike catalogs.](https://wethepeoplebmx.de/catalogs)
This is one of their [2010 catalog](https://issuu.com/wemakethings/docs/wtpbmxparts2010) with the logo on the cover

[image]
When asking questions please be sure to include any information / clues you may have. Your comment "said to be WTP Justice" was the key to finding the logo.

Comment: My eyes are not as good as they once were but I'm pretty sure that's a completely different logo, it could have changed over time I guess

Comment: @DanK I understand your skepticism. The picture in the posted question could be a little clearer. It's hard to tell for sure if the frame stamp has the lightning bolts actually crossing at the bottom because of the shadow. As near as I can tell they do cross on the frame stamp.

Comment: I understand to be a little clearer next time first hand. I had posted the question away from computer where the seller mentioned his thoughts on what he believed it was- (I couldn’t remember exactly so waited until was home and updated the info)  but great help and appreciate all you’re feedback!